# General Probability Question from a problem I am having

Tags: probability, statistics

So I have a question that I already have an answer to thanks to my teacher, and it should be simple, but I can't wrap my brain around it.

"If a couple wants to have 3 children, what is the probability that 2 will be girls and one will be a boy?" supposedly, the answer to the 3rd decimal place is .375. I don't understand how that is the answer. I would assume the chance to have 2 girls out of 3 children would be 2/3 or .667 (to 3 decimal places) and the chance to have a boy would be .333(to 3 decimal places). Where am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The possible gender patterns (sorting by age, say) are $BBB,BBG,BGB,GBB,BGG,GBG,GGB,GGG$  These are equi-probable (under standard assumptions) and three of them meet your requirements.

Comment: For intuition:  it's clear (isn't it?) that the answer would be the same if you asked for two boys and one girl.  But these cases are mutually exclusive so your answer would make the probability of two of one gender one of the other  equal to  $\frac 23+\frac 23=\frac 43>1$ which is absurd.

Comment: you are thinking about something completely different: What is the probability that if they **did** have 2 girls and 1 boy to choose from, and pick one of them randomly, it would be one of the girls/one of the boys? But they are not picking them from a given set, like puppies in a store, are they?

Comment: @Al-geBra You say that the probability of $2$ girls is $2/3$ but think about it like this. The probability of any child being a girl is $1/2$. Assuming the first child is a girl, the ways you'd have $2$ girls are if the second child or the third child are girls. So (since each event is mutually exclusive) the probability should actually be $P(\text{first child is girl})\cdot P(\text{second child...})+P(\text{first...})\cdot P(\text{third...})=\frac12\cdot\frac12+\frac12\cdot\frac12=\frac12$. Note that this also includes the event $GGG$.

Comment: Aside: the problem as you have stated it is rather odd, as it is asking for a probability of an event conditional on the wishes of the participants in the event. I think it should read "if a couple have 3 children ...".

Comment: Is there some kind of rule I could use o make this easier?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the probability of girls and boys is equal ($0.5$ each), and that the events are independent.  Hence, in order to have $2$ girls out of $3$ kids, you have to "choose" the order of birth, that is $\binom{3}{2} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}=3$, which you may see as all the possible arrangements of $2$ girls and $1$ boy. Further, you have to multiply by the probability of having $2$ boys and $1$ girl, i.e., $\frac{1}{2^2}\frac{1}{2}$, namely the probability of interest is 
$$
\binom{3}{2}\frac{1}{2^3}\,. 
$$